# 'Are' or 'were' examples (in the past)?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past

If a group of deceased persons stand out as a good example in the past, and that their example is definitely worth following now, do I say that they 'were' good examples to us; or do I say that they 'are' good examples to us ?

Comment: Are they still good examples? Are you talking about when they were good examples then, or about whether they are good examples now?

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say they "are good examples" because the emphasis is on when the example they provide is good.

Examples:

"They were good examples to us [before they destroyed the world]."

"They are good examples to us [, we should honour their memories]."

Comment: The question includes 'their example is definitely worth following now' so I expect - I hope - that would discount any globally destructive tendencies.

Comment: Hehe. You could actually say something like this too: "They were good examples to us, and still are."

Comment: Well, I think the Moderators might mark you down there, for expressing an opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say I have expressed an opinion. Unless you're referring to my usage examples?

Comment: I was being facetious about your global remark. Not to worry. Ignore it. Regards.